# Redux state with local state concerning API calls

Tags: reactjs, redux

I came across interesting article (Link at the end of post). Author of the article states, that they treat redux store as client-side database and UI logic does not fit there (If it's not needed for unrelated components), even for data fetching purposes. For example we want to show some loading spinner when fetching some data:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({isLoading: true});
  await this.props.fetchSomeData();
  this.setState({isLoading: false});
}
```

We fire async thunk action that fetches some data that is needed for more than one component or we want to cache that data, even when that component is unmounted.

The only component that is concerned about loading state is the one in which we fire thunk action, other components are not concerned about state of loading. But I always see redux examples with async actions creators which fire REQUEST/SUCCESS/FAILURE actions types and reducers bloated with loading states even if they're are used in one component.

I can see some cons of this code, that some state lives in component and some in redux, but pros are that redux store is not bloated with state that is not needed for other components, also we can avoid the verbosity of redux.

So my question would be, what are cons of this state separation regarding this particular example ?

Article: https://dev.bleacherreport.com/3-things-i-learned-about-working-with-data-in-redux-5fa0d5f89c8b 
(Also interesting discussion in article comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, some of the cons of your state separation approach is that:

1. If there is complex API fetching behind the scene ( fetch A then fetch B then fetch C) `redux-thunk` would be inadequate and you will have to use `redux-saga` or `redux-observable` and together with them, the REQUEST/SUCCESS/FAILURE styles.
2. If, in the future, there are other components need to listen to the 'loading' state or worse need the same data but there is no guarantee that the order of display them will be the same ( A mount and fetch data and then B mount before the data is fetched, and B fetch again ), you will have to refactor all the structures. And that doesn't count the case when you need to CANCEL a fetch.
3. If your component unmount before the data is fetched, the "this.setState" call will result in a null reference error.

In general, I agree that UI state should be put in the component, but global state must always be stored in the Redux store and your `isLoading` is not totally a UI state but a state of the request that your component are listening to.